# Understanding get second lowest and second highest value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

Good day fellow Stack-ers,

I must ask your pardon if this question has been asked before or if it seems elementary (I am only a Javascript novice).

[I have been doing w3c js challenges lately:](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-functions-exercises.php) *Write a JavaScript function which will take an array of numbers stored and find the second lowest and second greatest numbers.*

Here is my answer:

```
var array = [3,8,5,6,5,7,1,9];
var outputArray = [];

function arrayTrim() {
  var sortedArray = array.sort();
  outputArray.push(sortedArray[1],array[array.length-2]);
  return outputArray;
}

arrayTrim();
```

and here is the answer that they have provided:

```
function Second_Greatest_Lowest(arr_num) {  
  arr_num.sort(function(x,y) {  
    return x-y;
  });  

  var uniqa = [arr_num[0]];  
  var result = [];  

  for(var j=1; j < arr_num.length; j++) {  
    if(arr_num[j-1] !== arr_num[j]) {
      uniqa.push(arr_num[j]);  
    }  
  }

  result.push(uniqa[1],uniqa[uniqa.length-2]);
  return result.join(',');  

}  

alert(Second_Greatest_Lowest([1,2,3,4,5]));
```

I know that the for loop runs through until the length of the input, *but I don't understand the if statement nested within the for loop*. It seems like a long way around to the solution.

Thank you!

Comment: What happens in your solution if my numbers are `1,2,3,4,5,5` - do I get the second to highest number from your function? What about the provided correct solution?

Comment: It seems to sort them (as numbers, not lexically as you do), then it filters out duplicates by pushing only unique values to `uniqa`, then it takes the second-lowest and second-highest value from that.

Comment: It should have been forbidden to use `sort()` in this challenge.

Comment: what makes you say that @Danny_ds? I'd be interested to hear you rationale

Comment: @AaronMatthews - Sort() is a very expensive operation ( O(n log n) at best) and needs random access to the data (a lot). It is not needed at all to find the two numbers - those can be found using one sequential pass through the data (which also better utilizes the cpu cache). Since this is a learning exercise/challenge they should have forbidden to use sort(). Of course, on 10 numbers it won't make a big difference, but on millions (or even data that won't fit in memory) it will. You'll understand this even better after solving exercise no. 24 (bubble sort) on that same page.

Comment: ~aha, well as you said it's a training exercise so I'll reconsider my approach ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer does not perform correct for input such as f.e. `[3,8,5,6,5,7,1,1,9]`. Your proposed solution returns `1` as the second lowest number here – whereas it should actually be `3`.

The solution suggested by the site takes that into account – that is what the `if` inside the loop is for, it checks if the current number is the same as the previous one. If that’s the case, it gets ignored. That way, every  number will occur once, and that in turn allows to blindly pick the second element out of that sorted array and actually have it be the second lowest number.

> It seems like a long way around to the solution

You took a *short cut*, that does not handle all edge cases correctly ;-)

Comment: Thank you @CBoe, that's quite a gap in my answer to the problem

Answer (score 2):

The loop in question:

```
for(var j=1; j < arr_num.length; j++) {  
    if(arr_num[j-1] !== arr_num[j]) {
      uniqa.push(arr_num[j]);  
    }  
  }
```

Provides some clue as to what it's doing by using a (reasonably) descriptive variable name: `uniqa` - or "unique array". The `if` statement is checking that the current element is not the same as the previous element - having sorted the array initially this works to give you a unique array - by only filling a new array if the element is indeed unique.

Thereafter the logic is the same as yours.

Answer (score 1):

import java.util.Arrays;

```
public class BubbleWithMax_N_Min
{
    public static void main(String[] agrs)
    {

        int temp;
        int[] array = new int[5];
        array[0] = 3;
        array[1] = 99;
        array[2] = 55;
        array[3] = 2;
        array[4] = 1;

        System.out.println("the given array is:" + Arrays.toString(array));
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(array[i] + "");
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                {

                    for (int j = 1; j < array.length - i; j++)
                    {

                        if (array[j - 1] > array[j])
                        {

                            temp = array[j - 1];
                            array[j - 1] = array[j];
                            array[j] = temp;

                        }

                    }
                }

                System.out.println(" 2nd Min and 2nd Highest:");
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(array[i+1]);

                }
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            int a= array.length-2;
            System.out.println(array[a]);

        }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Java Code To Get 2nd Max and 2nd Min